# Wondering if it's possible to program something that can deal with the massive number of possible combinations in a deck of 52 cards

Tags: python

They say there are 8.06e+67 different combinations that can be made from a deck of 52 cards, a number that's really too big for a human mind to comprehend, and (I'm assuming) too big for any computer to handle as well. But my question is, if you establish a hierarchy of cards in some code, e.g. from A-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-J-Q-K, and then D,H,S,C for the suits, is it possible to write something that will tell you, for example, what the combination #45,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 is without having to run through all of them to get there? Or, if you could feed in a specific combination of 52 cards, is there a way to quickly find out what its number would be without having to run through all of them?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Is that all you wanted to know?

Comment: Sort of! But my other question is, is it practical? i.e. would it take forever for an average computer to calculate these numbers from either direction, or is it something that most computers could handle fairly quickly and easily without blowing up?

Comment: No number is beyond the ability of the right bignum library. :)

Comment: @sens: Why don't you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code and try it out yourself?  If you get stuck with the coding, *that* would make for an appropriate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: And yes, it's possible (and fast, and not terribly difficult) to map a deck number to a deck. And back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by factorially dividing the given number and using the remainder as a card index in the remaining deck:

```
def card_combination(n, deck=list(range(52))):
    if len(deck) == 0:
        return ()
    index = n % len(deck)
    return (card(deck[index]), *card_combination(n // len(deck), deck[:index] + deck[index+1:]))

# given a card number between 0 and 51, convert it to the string representation of the card
def card(n):
    return 'DHSC'[n // 13] + 'A234567891JQK'[n % 13] + ('0' if n % 13 == 9 else '')

def combination_number(cards, deck=list(range(52))):
    if len(deck) == 0:
        return 0
    index = deck.index(number(cards[0]))
    return index + combination_number(cards[1:], deck[:index] + deck[index+1:]) * len(deck)

# given a string representation of card, convert it to the card number
def number(card):
    return 'DHSC'.find(card[0]) * 13 + (int(card[1:]) - 1 if card[1].isdigit() else ('JQKA'.index(card[1]) % 4 + 10) % 13)

for n in 0, 1, 52, 45000000000000000000000:
    cards = card_combination(n)
    print(cards)
    print(combination_number(cards))
```

This outputs (given combination number 0, 1, 52 and OP's requested number, convert to card combination and then convert it back):

```
('DA', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'DJ', 'DQ', 'DK', 'HA', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'H10', 'HJ', 'HQ', 'HK', 'SA', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SK', 'CA', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CK')
0
('D2', 'DA', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'DJ', 'DQ', 'DK', 'HA', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'H10', 'HJ', 'HQ', 'HK', 'SA', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SK', 'CA', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CK')
1
('DA', 'D3', 'D2', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'DJ', 'DQ', 'DK', 'HA', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'H10', 'HJ', 'HQ', 'HK', 'SA', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SK', 'CA', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CK')
52
('H8', 'C9', 'H7', 'CA', 'D4', 'S7', 'D6', 'S5', 'S2', 'C10', 'HQ', 'DJ', 'H6', 'H2', 'DA', 'D2', 'D3', 'D5', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'DQ', 'DK', 'HA', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H9', 'H10', 'HJ', 'HK', 'SA', 'S3', 'S4', 'S6', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SK', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CK')
45000000000000000000000
```

Comment: This allows for repeated cards, which may or may not be appropriate depending on what you're asking.

Comment: Indeed. I've re-implemented my answer with no repeating card.

Comment: OK I've fixed my code and fully solved it, both converting a number to a card combination and converting the card combination back to the number.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is just a search tree. One possible example off the top of my head:

Level 0: The root (1 node)
Level 1: The suit (4 nodes)
Level 2: The number (13 nodes)

This tree has 52 leaf nodes, representing every possible card.

If you wanted the first card in this tree, do a 0-0 traversal (0 being the index of the child at each level). If you wanted the second card, do a 0-1, and so on.

The (poorly-drawn) tree would look something like this:

```
                 root
          /       |           \                 \
     /            |             \                \
   hearts          spade           club        diamond
   ...            / | | \          ...           ...
                  A 2 3 4 ...
```

To get combinations, say for a hand of 4 cards, have 4 separate trees that represent each of the 4 cards in your hand. Since we already know how to get the n-th card in a single tree, and that each tree has 52 possible cards, finding any arbitrary combination is just a matter of simple modulo arithmetic to find which path in each tree you have to take.

**NOTE**: This "top of my head" implementation is not exactly accurate, because it allows for duplicate cards, but one could tweak this to disallow repeats. One possible solution is to remove a leaf after it has been used. My naive implementation would give 52^52 possible combinations, while the true number of combinations is `52!`.

In this case, you would want to modify your algorithm to operate like this:

1. Let the combination number be n
2. Let the number of remaining cards in your deck be r
3. Find the first card by doing n % r
4. Remove this card from the tree
5. let n = n / r
6. If n < 1, stop.
7. Else, let r = r - 1, and go back to step 3.

You'll note that even when removing leaves from the tree, the algorithm still behaves deterministically, so any given combination number will always return the same result. There are also some details I left out, such as the traversal algorithm that can appropriately find the nth leaf. Also, there may be other data structures more suited to this task, but again this is just "off the top of my head."

Also, this is a O(nlogn) solution, which is reasonable enough for a computer to do.